# mysql stored proc returning one row

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am working with php myadmin and I am trying to create a very simple stored routine.  I would like to select two columns from all rows in a table. When I run:

```
select start_date, stop_date from trip;
```

I get the results I expect.  When I create a stored proc with the same query it only returns the first row.  I thought I may be writing it wrong so I tried the php myadmin routine wizard and get the same results.  For reference, I created the routine with this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_trip_dates()
begin
select start_date, stop_date from trip;
end;;
```

delimiter set to ;;

I verified that it is in fact returning only the first row and not php myadmin cutting results off or something by doing a var_dump on the result set.

Comment: Include the PHP code that is retrieving the data. You are probably using a function to get a single row, instead of all the rows.

Comment: when I test the routine within php myadmin by itself it is returning the first row.  So this problem is independent of php at the moment.

Comment: Try executing `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE get_trip_dates;` to ensure it's actually set to what you expect.

Comment: I would take phpmyadmin out of the loop. Perhaps it has a bug.